# Refactoring two lists of strings

Tags: c#, .net

I have two lists of strings. One is object friendly name and other one is object class name.

```
"Car","Animal","Plane"

"MachineClass","AnimalClass","FlyClass".
```

I use friendly names to show user input and class names to dynamically create class instances by using reflection, so i need both lists and like you can see "Car" as friendly name can be bound to "Machine.cs".

I need some more creative way of working and translating both of these lists rather than using switch statement which converts from one string to other, those lists have numerous items and i can make small spelling which will cause error. Moreover sometimes, i send string of test name for evaluation whereas same problem with spellings can apply there.

I tried to think about using enums but still digits doesn't ring a bell for conversions between both lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 public enum Things
 {
     Car,
     Animal,
     Plane
 }

 var dict = new Dictionary<Things, string> {
      { Things.Car, "MachineClass" },
      { Things.Animal, "AnimalClass" },
      { Things.Plane, "FlyClass" } };

 string classname = dict[Things.Plane]; // FlyClass
```

Now if you wanted real types, that you can instantiate:

```
var realtypes = dict.ToDictionary(
        kvp => kvp.Key,
        kvp => System.Type.GetType("Namespace." + kvp.Value));
```

A fully working example is on http://ideone.com/TTuBP:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

//public interface IThing {} 
public class MachineClass /* : IThing */ { }
public class AnimalClass  /* : IThing */ { }
public class Plane        /* : IThing */ { }

public class Program
{
     public enum Things
     {
         Car,
         Animal,
         Plane
     }

     private static readonly IDictionary<Things, string> _classNameMap = 
         new Dictionary<Things, string> {
          { Things.Car,    "MachineClass" },
          { Things.Animal, "AnimalClass"  },
          { Things.Plane,  "FlyClass"     }  };

     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         var realtypes = _classNameMap.ToDictionary(
                 kvp => kvp.Key,
                 kvp => System.Type.GetType(/*"Namespace." +*/ kvp.Value));

         Type dynamicType = realtypes[Things.Plane]; // typeof(Namespace.FlyClass)

         foreach (var realtype in realtypes)
             Console.WriteLine("{0}, class {1}", 
                     realtype.Key, realtype.Value);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a dictionary?

```
Dictionary<string, string> classMap_ = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

classMap_["Car"] = "MachineClass";
classMap_["Animal"] = "AnimalClass";
classMap_["Plane"] = "FlyClass":
```

Creating the appropriate class is as simple as:

```
string className = classMap_["Car"];
```

Comment: Still i will need to write down "Car"... moreover sometimes class friendly name is not only parameter from which i make decision what class name to bind.

Comment: @eugeneK, perhaps you can expand your question a bit then.  Conceivably we could create an entire key with all your requirements in (names, and whatever else) and use it as the key type in the dictionary (implementing the appropriate interfaces)?  Can you expand on that in your question?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use maps HashMap to maintain friendly name and class name mapping

Answer (score 0):

I don't recomend to use reflection for creation objects of classes from performance point of view, insteed you can use lambda expressions to create objects
look at the following code

```
            var animals = new Dictionary<string, Func<object>>
                          {
                              {"Animal 1", () => new MyAnimal1()},
                              {"Animal 2", () => new MyAnimal2()}
                          };

        var createAnimal = animals["Animal 1"];
        var animal = createAnimal();
```

where

```
    private class MyAnimal1
    {

    }

    private class MyAnimal2
    {

    }
```

insteed this classes you should use your classes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using databinding?

```
class Wrapper
{
  public string UserFriendly{get;set;}
  public string Technical{get;set;}
}

var data = new[]
{
    new Wrapper("Car", "MachineClass"),
    new Wrapper("Plane", "FlyClass"),
};

combo.Datasource = data;
combo.DisplayMember = "UserFriendly";
combo.ValueMember = "Technical";
```

Combo will display the friendlyname but when asking for SelectedValue you will get the technical name.

Comment: It's not that simple, i use those list thought all project not only for databinding comboboxes